# Why IConfigurationRoot GetConnectionString is returning null?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to read a .json file in my Asp.net Core project.

## Print

[image]

## dbConfig.json

```
{
  "AzureCosmosDb": {
    "EndpointUrl": "https://localhost:8081",
    "PrimaryKey": "C2y6yDjf5/R++4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw/Jw==",
    "DatabaseId": "Cosmoso"
  },
  "Oracle12c": {

  }
}
```

## Code to search for the values in the file in `dbConfig.Json`:

```
public static string GetConnectionString(string fileJson, string conexao)
{
  var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile(fileJson);

  Configuration = builder.Build();

   string connection = Configuration.GetConnectionString("AzureCosmosDb:DatabaseId");
   return connection;
}
```

The method is returning null, what's wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`Configuration.GetConnectionString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.configurationextensions.getconnectionstring?view=aspnetcore-2.1) looks for a configuration section with the name `"ConnectionStrings"`, so you would have to adjust your configuration like this for the method to work:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "AzureCosmosDb": {
      "DatabaseId": "Cosmoso"
    }
  }
}
```

But since you have other configurations there as well that are not connection strings, I would just suggest you to not use `GetConnectionString` at all and just retrieve the value directly:

```
string connection = Configuration["AzureCosmosDb:DatabaseId"];
```